# Reputation is decreased even after post is deleted

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation

Few minutes ago I downvoted an answer. At that time my reputation was decreased by 1.
But then user deleted that answer, and My reputation again decreased by 1 instead it should be increased by 1.
It is showing **+1** in reputation record, but actually 1 reputation is decreased.
Is it a bug ?

[image]

Comment: Scroll to the bottom and check "show removed posts".

Comment: @Mysticial it is checked.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your reputation tab? Downvotes and removed posts are only visible to you.

Comment: how to upload image??

Comment: It looks fine to me. Are you sure it decreased twice?

Comment: @Mysticial Yes it is... Earlier it was 1470 and now it 1468.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your reputation image, it clearly looks that the -1 reputation which you lost by downvoting an answer is recovered with +1.

Now as you said, your reputation was 1470 and now it is showing 1468 one post ( question/answer ) got deleted on which you did **suggested edit** , this could be a reason for your reputation change.

Comment: ohh.. thnx.. this could be the reason..